# Define BASE structure when using PROC APPEND with empty BASE

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a single dataset through iterations of a macro loop. I have found that proc append does not need a defined BASE in order to be used, so approach should be viable. However, I am running into a problem with variable name lengths.

I have created a simple, reproducible example that demonstrates my problem. Of course this is not the most efficient way to create my final `want` dataset, but this process simulates the workflow in my code.

```
proc sql;
    select name from sashelp.class;
    select name
        into :name_1 - :name_&sqlobs
    from sashelp.class;
quit;

%macro forward_loop;
%do i = 1 %to 10;
    proc sql;
    create table temp as
    select
    "&&name_&i" as name,
    age
    from sashelp.class
    quit;
    proc append base=want data=temp;
    run;
%end;
%mend;

%forward_loop;
```

> NOTE: Appending WORK.TEMP to WORK.WANT.
>
> WARNING: Variable name has different lengths on BASE and DATA files (BASE 6 DATA 7).
>
> ERROR: No appending done because of anomalies listed above. Use FORCE option to append these files.
>
> NOTE: 0 observations added.

I believe I can solve this in the proc sql step by simply designating that `name` is padded up to a certain standard length. However, I was unable to figure out how to do this.

Is this the right approach? Or is there a way to create a BASE structure without having any rows of data in BASE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create consistently structured datasets then letting PROC APPEND create the base dataset from the first incremental dataset will work fine.

In your example you are creating NAME from a string literal without telling SAS how long to make the variable. So by default it will be created as long as the string literal.  If you are really using that method in PROC SQL then add the LENGTH attribute to the column definition in your SELECT statement.

```
"&&name_&i" as name length=8
```

If you are actually doing it with a data step then define the length before assigning the variable a value.

```
length name $8;
name = "&&name_&i";
```

But it might be best to just define the BASE dataset first before entering the loop.

```
data want;
  length name $8 age 8 ;
  stop;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply create an dataset with datastep. `stop` will ensure that no Observations will be written. But than you also have to use `FORCE` to get the smaller ones into the dataset.

```
data want;
  length name $7;
  stop;
run;
```

Alternative create the base dataset the same way but use insert into instead of proc append.

Comment: Which is less resource intensive? Lots of proc sql inserts, or lots of proc appends with the data step every x number of iterations? My actual macro has a `%while(&continue=1)` step, and inside of that it iterates over a set of calculations, preparing the want table which is then used to determine if we continue.

Comment: It depends of the rest of the code when the dataset to be appended i s created by create table i would use insert into instead. When it is generated by something else proc append.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to understand if your example is actually what you want to do.

Define the LENGTH of name in PROC SQL.

```
proc sql noprint;
    *select name from sashelp.class;
   select name into :name_1- from sashelp.class;
   quit;
%put _global_;

%macro forward_loop;
%do i = 1 %to 10;
   proc sql;
      create table temp_&i as
      select 
      "&&name_&i" as name length=8,
      age
      from sashelp.class
      quit;
   %end;
   %mend;
   options mprint=1;
   %forward_loop;

data want;
   if 0 then set sashelp.class(keep=name age);
   set temp_: open=defer;
   run;
```